# Get only four objects by type and date LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I`m novice in programming, looking for any advise.

I have a list of patients in clinic, each patient has one of these type: "child", "teenager", "adult", "oldage" and also has the date of the visit to the doctor.

The issue to get from list of patients only four patients, one patient of each type and has the latest date of the last doctor's visit.

I can do this by four separate request to db.

```
var childPatient = await db.patientsOfClinic.Where(x => x.TypeOfPatient == "child").OrderByDescending(x => x.UploadedDate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But need to handle it by one request to db.

Tried such request, but it incorrect.

```
var patientsOfClinic = await db.patientsOfClinic.Where(x => x.ClinicId == clinicId && x.TypeOfPatient == "child" && x.TypeOfPatient == "teenager" && x.TypeOfPatient == "adult" && x.TypeOfPatient == "oldage").OrderByDescending(y => y.UploadedDate).ToListAsync();
```

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: you are using and to TypeOfPatient so it never going to return any value patient can't be both child and teenager use or '||'  instead.

Comment: @coder_b if I will use or ||, I will not get all types of patient

Comment: well I thought only you have 4 types. in that case what properties would you like to see patientsOfClinic collection. so can group and select the properties you want send as an anonymous collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

First, sort the patients by the upload date.

Then group them by the type. you will get 4 groups ordered by date.

The from each group, take the first patient which is also latest.

This will yield a list of 4 patients, one of each group, with the latest UploadDate.

```
var patients = db.patientsOfClinic.OrderByDescending(patient => patient.UploadDate)
                                  .GroupBy(patient => patient.TypeOfPatient)
                                  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result =  from p in db.patientsOfClinic 
    group p by p.TypeOfPatient into grp 
    select grp.OrderByDescending(o => o.UploadedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I need to get the list of four patients with different types, and latest date, by this example I will get only one patient.

Comment: @AlexKubin, have you tried that? It is theoretically right query but it will be not translated to the SQL.

Comment: @Alex Kubin: You will get one client of each type with latest `UploadedDate`!

Comment: yes right, but I need to get list of four patients with different type by latest date

Comment: @Svyatoslav yes, I tried, it close, but here I get only one patient,  I need to get list of four patients with different type by latest date

Comment: @Alex Kubin: You right, I fixed, the sorting is changed to `.OrderByDescending()`. Now will be latest. If you will provide the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it will be possible to help more accurately.

Comment: @Alex Kubin: By the way, if this is a database with a large amount of data, then it is preferable to describe this request in a storage procedure that will be executed on the server and return only the final result.

Answer (score 0):

This query needs grouping and join to that group.

```cs
// make reusable filtered set
var filtered = db.patientsOfClinic.Where(p => x.ClinicId == clinicId);

var grouped = 
   from p in filtered
   group p by p.TypeOfPatient into g
   select new
   {
      TypeOfPatient = g.Key,
      UploadedDate = g.Max(x.UploadedDate)
   };

var result = 
   from p in filtered
   join g in grouped on new { p.TypeOfPatient, p.UploadedDate } 
                 equals new { g.TypeOfPatient, g.UploadedDate }
   select p;
```

Comment: any way, first I have to get the whole list from db and then do like you show? if for examle I have fifty thousand patients and first a get the whole list of fifty thousand, then to get only four patient by type,

Comment: It is single database query. just combined from variables.

Comment: yes, I see, but I think it`s not reasonable to get whole list of fifty thousand patients from db, if I have get list of only four patients.

Comment: If you do not call `ToList`, `ToArray`, ect. - nothing is grabbled from database. It is query decomposition - you create parts of query and combine them.

Comment: look, again why I need get List of the whole patient, can I by one request do some sort and get List only of four patient. I understand that without ToList i will not get any list

Comment: @AlexKubin, instead of starting discussion, just run the query. I'm not a novice in the SQL and especially LINQ. And I know any variations of this query. Fastest here is using ROW_NUMBER, but EF will not allow to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use lambda expressions in this case to return anonymous object which gives you  list of patent type with the patent where max uploaded date is true.

To test:

```
public class PatientsOfClinic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClinicId { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfPatient { get; set; }
    public DateTime UploadedDate { get; set; }
}


     var listOfPatents = new List<PatientsOfClinic>
           {
               new PatientsOfClinic
               {
                   Id =1 ,  
                   ClinicId=1,
                   TypeOfPatient = "child",
                   UploadedDate = DateTime.Today
               },
               new PatientsOfClinic
               {
                   Id =1 ,
                   ClinicId=1,
                   TypeOfPatient = "teenager",
                   UploadedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
               }
            };
            var clinicId = 1;
                //listOfPatents
    //        .Where(c => c.ClinicId == clinicId)
    //        .GroupBy(x => x.TypeOfPatient)
    //        .Select(g => new
    //        {
    //            TypeOfPatient = g.Key,
    //            Patient = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.UploadedDate)
    //                             .FirstOrDefault()
    //        });

    listOfPatents
        .Where(c => c.ClinicId == clinicId)
        .GroupBy(x =>  x.TypeOfPatient)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Where(u=>u.UploadedDate == g.Max(m =>m.UploadedDate)))
}
```

Comment: i think `Patient = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.UploadedDate).FirstOrDefault()` will work fine for linq to objects, but will not translated to sql by EF.

Comment: @Sajid updated code to translate EF query hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

> The issue to get from list of patients only four patients, one patient of each type...

The first thing you need to do, when someone says: I need items with a certain value of a property, is you should think of one of the overload of [Queryable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-5.0)

With this method, you make groups of Patients that have some value in common. In your case, you make groups of Patients that have the same value for property `TypeOfPatient`.

The result is you get a group of Patients with TypeOfPatient value equal to Child, and a group of Patients with TypeOfPatient value equal to Adult, etc.

But you don't just want Group of patients, from every Group you want to select one item.

> ... of each type and has the latest date of the last doctor's visit.

For this you use parameter resultSelector. This parameter is a method with two input values: the common item, in your case the TypeOfPatient, and all Patients that are in the group. The output is one object. In your case: you want as output the Patient of the group that has the newest data of doctor's visit.

```
IQueryable<Patient> patients = ...
var result = patients.GroupBy(patient => patient.TypeOfPatient,

    // parameter resultSelector: take each found TypeOfPatient,
    // with all Patients that have this value for TypeOfPatient,
    // to make one new:
    (typeOfPatient, patientsOfThisType) =>

        // order all patients in this group by descending value for UploadedDate
        // and take the first
        patientsWithOfType.OrderByDescending(patient => patient.UploadedDate)
                          .FirstOrDefault());
```

You can be certain that there won't be any empty groups. So there will always be a first one.